# Keep cookies between tests nightwatch selenium

Tags: selenium, cookies, nightwatch.js

I need to keep some cookies from test to test, I'm using Nightwatch and Selenium, I don't know how to get them for the current session o where to store them.

I've tried to create and set an account, but that doesn't seem to work either

```
 "selenium" : {
"start_process" : false,
"server_path" : "",
"log_path" : "",
"host" : "127.0.0.1",
"port" : 4444,
"cli_args" : {
  "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
  "webdriver.ie.driver" : "",
  "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "webdriver"
}
  },
```

Any help is apreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v0.9.14, [setCookie](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/setCookie.html) does not persist cookies between tests.  It looks like the client is created anew for each test.

What I've done is create a [custom command](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands) that sets and caches the cookie value.  This works well for maintaining* authentication state between tests since the custom commands are singletons.  The actual authentication only happens once, then subsequent calls use [setCookie](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/setCookie.html) with the cached session value.

Keep in mind that [setCookie](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/setCookie.html) won't work until the client has navigated to the relevant domain.

Comment: curious how did you cache the cookie? inside nightwatchs globals?

Comment: Yeah (agreeing with Hans). Can you show an example, how you cache the values? Pretty please with sugar on top. :-)

Comment: I would if I had access to that computer or code base any longer!  From memory, I was just abusing a side effect, storing the cookie globally or in the session.

Answer (score -2):

How can we set cookies in Nightwatch. I was tried in Supertest it's works.
How to do in nightwatch.

Below is the code to work with superTest

```
var args = {

            data: {
                    email: "xxxx",
                    password: "xxxx"
                },
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            };
            service.post("localhost", args, function(data, response) {
                global.Cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'].pop().split(';')[0]
                this.meServiceUrl = superTest.agent("localhost/users").get('');
                // Set cookie to get saved user session
                this.meServiceUrl.cookies = Cookies;
                this.meServiceUrl.set('Accept', 'application/json')
                    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                    .expect(200)
                    .end(function(err, res) {
                        usersApiResponse = res.body
                        usersServiceResponse.push(usersApiResponse)
                    console.log(usersServiceResponse)
                        console.log(usersApiResponse.result.length)
                    });
            });
```